# Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Common.Exceptions.UnathorizedException

Tags: c#, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

Hi Team I have the following code in C#, i am writting a backend-application using C# to read DeviceToCloudMEssage in Azure portal;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Common;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;


namespace BackEndApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        private static ServiceClient _serviceClient;

        private readonly static string s_connectionString = "HostName=UniversityIOTHub.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=UniversityDeviceIOT;SharedAccessKey=******=";
        private static async Task InvokeMethod()
        {

            var methodInvocation = new CloudToDeviceMethod("SetTelemetryInterval") { ResponseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) };
            methodInvocation.SetPayloadJson("10");

            var response = await _serviceClient.InvokeDeviceMethodAsync("UniversityDeviceIOT", methodInvocation);
            Console.WriteLine("Response status:{0}, payload", response.Status);
            Console.WriteLine(response.GetPayloadAsJson());

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IOT Hub Test-- BackEndApplication.\n");

            _serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(s_connectionString);
            InvokeMethod().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


}
```

I am getting an authorizedException from the assemblies, one being Microsoft.Azure.Device.Common. The exception hits on InvokeMethod().GetAwaiter().GetResult(). Im also using DeviceExplore to test this exception, payload method i am also getting the same result. Please help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in your program is not reading DeviceToCloudMessages but invoking a direkt method.

For that you are using the wrong connectionString.  The ServiceClient does not connect to your device but to IoT-Hub.  So instead of using the IoT-Hub-Device connection string you have to use the IoT-Hub connection string which looks like this:

```
HostName=<yourIotHub>.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=<yourSharedAccessKey>=
```

Then you should be able to call _serviceClient.InvokeDeviceMethodAsync.  This will make the IoT-Hub trigger the direct method on the device and pass on the response to the calling program.

Comment: It sees the connectionString, but the problem is on the DeviceNOTFOund exception, that deviceID deos exist on the Hub and its new. s_serviceClient.InvokeDeviceMethodAsync("TestDeviceId", methodInvokation);

Comment: You have to make sure that your device is connected to IoT-Hub and that your device has implemented a handler for the "SetTelemetryInterval" direct method.

Comment: well apperantly all those are met, my connectionString is fine and it does connect to the IOT. If i use DeviceExplore to send message it send well and can see it from the portal. Problem is on the client side(C#) application it does not seem to connect with time out as DeviceNOTFOund. Im stuck to troubleshoot this issue, i has raise it to GitHub for more clarity and havent not receieved yet any response from the team.